# flutter firebase cloud function json exception

Tags: flutter

i am testing firebase_cloud function with flutter
and in index.js file i wrote like below

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {
    message: "Hello World"
  };
});
```

and i call the function like bellow

```dart
  var c = await aa.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'helloWorld');
  var cc = await c.call();
```

but when i run this code

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {message: Response is not valid JSON object., details: null, code: INTERNAL}))
```

flutter say like this
in javasscript it return json but why error occur?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but this problem still occurs. You have to specify the region you are calling the function in: HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: "your region code").getHttpsCallable....